# Timing in @keyframes animations

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

So I was making a simple project that would display a timer and count to 99 using just HTML and CSS.

But can anyone out there tell me why I need to put a delay on my 100s animation to get it to sync up with the 10s animation?

```css
.second::before {
  animation: time 100s linear 4.5s infinite;
  /* Why do I have to put a delay to get this to sync properly with the second counter!?? */
  content: "0";
}
.second::after {
  animation: time 10s linear infinite;
  content: "0";
}
@keyframes time {
  10% {
    content: "1"
  }
  20% {
    content: "2"
  }
  30% {
    content: "3"
  }
  40% {
    content: "4"
  }
  50% {
    content: "5"
  }
  60% {
    content: "6"
  }
  70% {
    content: "7"
  }
  80% {
    content: "8"
  }
  90% {
    content: "9"
  }
}
```

```html
 <span class="second"></span>
```

It seemed simple; count from 0 to 9 over 100 seconds, ie: one digit every ten seconds

Also count from 0 to 9 over 10 seconds, ie: one digit every second

**So why (without the delay) does the 100s animation display the first diget approx five seconds into the animation and then another digit every 10s after?**

CodePen example at the following: [oldTimer](http://codepen.io/Skibbereen-Coderdojo/pen/egLPvd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you set your animation, one value for 10% and another one for 20%, the change is happening at the mid point, that is 15%.

This means that one animation is off from what you believe by 0.5s, and the other by 5s. The net difference is 4.5s

To avoid that, set the steps to happen exactly where you want them:

```css
.second { font-size: 80px; }

.second::before {
  animation: time 100s linear infinite;
  /* Why do I have to put a delay to get this to sync properly with the second counter!?? */
  content: "0";
}
.second::after {
  animation: time 10s linear infinite;
  content: "0";
}
@keyframes time {
  0%, 9.99% {
    content: "0";
    background-color: blue;
    }
  10%, 19.99% {
    content: "1";
    background-color: green;
  }
  20%, 29.99% {
    content: "2";
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  30%, 39.99% {
    content: "3"
  }
  40%, 49.99% {
    content: "4"
  }
  50%, 59.99% {
    content: "5"
  }
  60%, 69.99% {
    content: "6"
  }
  70%, 79.99% {
    content: "7"
  }
  80%, 89.99% {
    content: "8"
  }
  90%, 100% {
    content: "9"
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="second"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @vals, that is absolutely perfect!
I actually fiddled around with the %'s to take advantage of the transition: http://codepen.io/Skibbereen-Coderdojo/pen/NdOgEj
But I prefer your solution for its accuracy in timing :)